# How can I synchronize a text with audio/sound in XNA/XACT?

Tags: xna

I wanted to display the text while sound is playing at background. In short if there is sound/audio for "What is this", I want to display the text "What is this" in text box synchronously. Is this possible with XNA/XACT? and can I use this in standard C# based WPF or Silverlight applications?

Appreciating your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if xna has any build in support for this but you could set up a second meta file that holds time and action information. For example mark a time for each word or phase spaken in a file and write out the text at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

same way as when making subtitles for movies. example:

```
00:02 Who are you?
00:05 An angel.
00:07 What's your name?
```

compare movie time with this, and show messages in texbox with some duration.